# Need help adding numbers in an array in C

Tags: c

I'm having an issue figuring out what I am missing here.  I need this program to sum the rainfall data for each of the 5 years.  It says I am missing a ( but not sure where.

Thanks for the help the code is:

```
#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5
#include <stdio.h>
// function prototypes
void inputdata();
void printdata();

// Global variables
// These are available to all functions
float sum=0.0, Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = {"2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"};
 char months[NUMMONTHS][12]      ={"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
int main ()
{


 char enterData = 'y';
 printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes)\n");
  scanf("%c",&enterData);
  if (enterData == 'y') {
    // Call Function to Input data
    inputdata();  

     // Call Function to display data
     printdata();
       }
       else {
         printf("No data was input at this time\n");
       }
       printf("Please try the Precipitation program again. \n");
       return 0;
    }
    // function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
  /* variable definition: */
  float Rain=1.0;  
   // Input Data
   for (int year=0;year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
          printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year+1, month+1);
          scanf("%f",&Rain);
          Raindata[year][month]=Rain;         
      }
   }
}
//Computation of total

for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        sum = sum + Raindata[year][month];
    }
}

// Function to printdata
void printdata(){
// Print data
   printf ("year\t month\t rain\n");
   for (int year=0; year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
          printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n",    years[year],months[month],Raindata[year][month]);         
     }      
   }
   //Printing of total
   printf("\nsum=%f", sum);
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated,  I have be reading and researching this issue but I can't find a similar example.

Comment: The error message for sure DOES tell you more precisely where it complains. Quote it in full and verbatim.

Comment: In case the error message contains a line number, please identify that line with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not part of a function

```
//Computation of total

for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        sum = sum + Raindata[year][month];
    }
}
```

You want  something like

```
void computeTotal() {
    //Computation of total
    for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
            sum = sum + Raindata[year][month];
        }
    }
}
```

or move it into `void inputdata()`

To get five different sums, you could either break it into five separate loops that sum a different variable, or change sum to an array.

```
float sum[NUMYEARS] = {0.0};

void computeTotal() {
    //Computation of total
    for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
            sum[year] += Raindata[year][month];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,  that is giving me the sum of all the data.  How do I get it to give me 5 sums, one for each year though?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
void inputdata() {
  /* variable definition: */
  float Rain=1.0;  
   // Input Data
   for (int year=0;year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
          printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year+1, month+1);
          scanf("%f",&Rain);
          Raindata[year][month]=Rain;         
      }
   }
}
//Computation of total

for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        sum = sum + Raindata[year][month];
    }
}
```

with this

```
void inputdata() {
  /* variable definition: */
  float Rain=1.0;  
   // Input Data
   for (int year=0;year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
          printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year+1, month+1);
          scanf("%f",&Rain);
          Raindata[year][month]=Rain;         
      }
   }

   //Computation of total

   for (int year=0;year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
       for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
           sum = sum + Raindata[year][month];
       }
   }
}
```